# Importing from validator in javascript

Tags: javascript, express

I want to use the validator for an express project. How do I import just two subsets of the packages directly?

Like:

```
import {isEmail, isEmpty} from 'validator';
```

or importing each on a separate line.

I just want to know if there is another option apart from import validator from 'validator'; as stated on the https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator

Comment: `import { isEmpty, isEmail } from 'validator';` works as does `const { isEmail, isEmpty } = require("validator")`

Comment: Using `import` in node.js is locked behind the `--experimental-modules` flag.  You also have to follow the `.mjs` extension convention.  See the [node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const isEmailValidator = require('validator').isEmail;
const isEmptyValidator = require('validator').isEmpty;


isEmailValidator('bla@bla.com');
```

Like this you mean? What you wrote should also be valid:

```
import {isEmail, isEmpty} from 'validator';

isEmail('bla@bla.com');
```

Edit for clarification: As you can see here https://github.com/chriso/validator.js/blob/master/src/index.js the library is exporting an object with each function. You can import everything `import validator from 'validator'` or you can use destructuring to get only a few properties.

Comment: Are you saying that I can import the two subsets as an object?

Comment: No, check this out. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: kindly show me an example how I would use destructuring to get only one property and its use

Comment: `import {isEmail} from 'validator';` then `isEmail('test@test.com')`

Answer (score 0):

```
const {isEmail, isEmpty} = require('validator');
```

This will not actually stop node from importing all of `validator` though.  This just has node load the `validator` object that is returned from that modules `export` and then destructures `isEmail` and `isEmpty` out of the exported Object.

Maybe whenever ES6 modules become full supported you can use the regular `import` syntax.  See [node.js documentation: ECMAScript Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).